# Cakephp3 - caching loaded results with dynamic key problem

Tags: caching, cakephp-3.x

I have a query:

```
$q = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Tab1')->find('OneById',
            ['id' => 1])->cache(function (Query $q) {
            return 'q' . md5(serialize($q->clause('where')));
        }, 'cQuestions')->first();
```

`cQuestions` is my custom cache config.

In every execute above query variable `$q` will have new values from database, despite the result of anonymous function is the same; Cache is reset.

When I change anonymous function to set cache key, like that:

```
function (Query $q) {
            return 'qtest';
        }
```

the problem with resetting cache disappeared.

Why ? The key cache is the same in both situation.

Comment: Are you positive that `md5(serialize($q->clause('where')));` is returning the same value in each fetch? Have you logged or `debug()` outputted it to check? Your usage appears correct otherwise. Possibly try adding debug calls to the QueryCacher to validate it's actually reading the expected key when first() gets called.

Comment: Yes, I receive the same md5 value (cache file is the same - it's only updated)